# NSString sizeWithFont not returning the correct height

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel

I've got a label and some other items in a scroll view. In -viewDidLoad, I set the text in the label and I want to increase the label's height so that all of the text fits. So, I calculate the size of the text constrained to the existing width of the label which a very, very large height constraint.

The height get calculated is too small though and the text is getting wrapped. I've tried this on the iOS4.3, iOS5.0 and iOS6.0 iPad simulators and it works incorrectly on all of them.

Any idea?

```
self.labelTextDescription.text = self.purchase.textDescription;
self.labelTextDescription.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

CGSize allowedSize = self.labelTextDescription.frame.size;
allowedSize.height = 100000;

CGSize textSize = [self.labelTextDescription.text sizeWithFont:self.labelTextDescription.font constrainedToSize:allowedSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Comment: that's strange, because this code works pretty good for me

Answer (score -1):

The number of lines for an UILabel is by default 1. You can calculate it yourself or as David Rönnqvist pointed out you can also use 0 (easier).
But your code itself isn't wrong.

Maybe this little code snippet will point you in the right direction.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";

CGSize allowedSize = CGSizeMake(100, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize textSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:allowedSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, textSize.width, textSize.height);
label.numberOfLines = 0; //EDIT: If you want to calculate it yourself use ceilf(textSize.height / label.font.lineHeight);
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: You can also use `label.numberOfLines = 0;` to "use as many lines as needed"

Comment: Woh didn't know that one, much easier. I've edited my answer. Thanks

Comment: Setting numberOfLines only controls how it will draw, it does not change the frame of the UILabel. You've misunderstood the question.

Comment: So what's the problem? Is the frame to small or is there only 1 line of text?